# reading from file and manipulate in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text  file:

it can change each time and the number of lines can be changed,  and contains the following for each line:

```
string (can contain one word, two or even more) ^ string of one word
EX:



level country ^ layla
hello sandra  ^ organization
hello people ^ layla
hello samar  ^ organization
```

I want to create dataframe using pandas such that:

```
item0   ( country, people)
item1    (sandra , samar)
```

Because for example each time there layla, we are returning the most right name that belongs to it and added it as the second column just shown above which is in this case ( country, people), and we called layla as item0 and as the index of the dataframe. I can't seem to arrange this and I don't know how to do the logic for returning the duplicated of whatever after the "^" and returning the list of its belonged most right name. My trial so far which doesn't really do it is:

```
def text_file(file):

    list=[]
    file_of_text = "text.txt"
    with open(file_of_context) as f:
         for l in f:
              l_dict = l.split(" ")
              list.append(l_dict)
    return(list)

def items(file_of_text):

     list_of_items= text_file(file_of_text)
     for a in list_of_items:
         for b in a:
             if a[-1]==



def main():

    file_of_text = "text.txt"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Now that you have added more text to your file, what's your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with pandas `read_csv()` Specifying '^' as your delimiter and using arbitrary column names

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter='\^', names=['A', 'B'])
print (df)
                A              B
0  level country           layla
1  hello sandra     organization
2   hello people           layla
3   hello samar     organization
```

then we split to get the values we want.  That expand arg is new in pandas 16 I believe

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[1]
print(df)
         A              B
0  country          layla
1   sandra   organization
2   people          layla
3    samar   organization
```

then we group column B and apply the tuple function.  Note: We're reseting the index so we can use it later

```
g = df.groupby('B')['A'].apply(tuple).reset_index()
print(g)
              B                  A
0          layla  (country, people)
1   organization    (sandra, samar)
```

Creating a new column with the string 'item' and the index

```
   g['item'] = 'item' + g.index.astype(str)
    print (g[['item','A']])
        item                  A
    0  item0  (country, people)
    1  item1    (sandra, samar)
```

Comment: typeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand',, anyway we can avoid using expand?

Comment: Yeah, you could something like `df['A'] = df['A'].map(lambda x : x.split()[1])`

Comment: are you assuming that A in the first df always two words? this can change and it can have one, two or three or even more, thus I'm having errors, anyway to avoid that?

Comment: Do you always want the value thats right before the "^"?

Comment: So instead of `df['A'] = df['A'].map(lambda x : x.split()[1])`  change that index to -1 so its `df['A'] = df['A'].map(lambda x : x.split()[-1])`

Comment: I'm having an error in case A has only one word like  (HE,),, it's having extra comma, how to avoid this?

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Index' objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126983/discussion-between-lelo-and-bob-haffner).

Comment: Shouldn't have a problem with the comma.   You should post a better representation of your data so we can see what we're dealing with

Comment: One last thing@Bob Haffner, can we make the names at col. A unique? remove any duplications at the tuple?

Comment: Instead of a tuple you could do a set

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your file is called `file_of_text.txt` and contains the following:

```
level country ^ layla
hello sandra  ^ organization
hello people ^ layla
hello samar  ^ organization
```

You can get your data from a file to a dataframe similar to your desired output with the following lines of code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def main(myfile):
    # Open the file and read the lines
    text = open(myfile,'r').readlines()

    # Split the lines into lists
    text = list(map(lambda x: re.split(r"\s[\^\s]*",x.strip()), text))

    # Put it in a DataFrame
    data = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['A','B','C'])

    # Create an output DataFrame with rows "item0" and "item1"
    final_data = pd.DataFrame(['item0','item1'],columns=['D'])

    # Create your desired column
    final_data['E'] = data.groupby('C')['B'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.values)).values

    print(final_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfile = "file_of_text.txt"
    main(myfile)
```

The idea is to read the lines from the text file and then split each line using the `split` method from the `re` module. The result is then passed to the `DataFrame` method to generate a dataframe called `data`, which is used to create the desired dataframe `final_data`. The result should look like the following:

```
# data

       A        B             C
0  level  country         layla
1  hello   sandra  organization
2  hello   people         layla
3  hello    samar  organization


# final_data

       D                  E
0  item0  (country, people)
1  item1    (sandra, samar)
```

Please take a look at the script and ask further questions, if you have any.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What if the length of the lines in the file change each time?

Comment: Please provide data that matches cases where _the lines in the file change each time_.

Comment: This is also assuming that there are only 2 words before "^", while it can vary.. how to adjust this?

Comment: the data can be changed each time! I need to make my code generalized because of that ! it can have 1000 thousands or sometimes less sometimes more, it should accept any lengeth

Comment: What you're saying makes very little sense. If your data changes, then you should provide a more general sample data in your question. Once you've done that, I can try and help further.